# Loading JSON into MVC Partial View when JSON comes from another api

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I have some JSON data that is being returned from a web api and I was wondering if there is a way to put that into a MVC partial view WITHOUT sending the data to the service?

I realize I can just build out the HTML when the data is returned from the service but I feel like there should just be an easier/cleaner way?  I want the functionality that I can build a 'template' in an MVC partial view but it all has to be rendered on the client javascript side.  Is there maybe a javascript library out there for doing this?

Comment: what difference does it make if you template it in browser or on server? If you are set on doing it at server can use your server as proxy to get the data and compile it

Comment: I was referring more to the structure of using a partial view as a template where you pass in your data model and you do @model.whatever where ever you need your data objects. My beef with the jquery approach is that I hate having to do .Append("<html here>" + data here + '<more html').  It just seems sloppy

Comment: There are numerous template engines for client side also. Not uncommon these days to have whole client side MVC apps that use no server side programming language other than delivering static html